# After death of Flash Player, can I still export MOVs from Flash Professional CS6?

Tags: flash

Adobe says it will "block Flash content from [running in Flash Player](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html) beginning January 12, 2021". Microsoft says it will "take steps to [remove Flash from the Windows operating system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/update-adobe-flash-support)". I'm running **Flash Professional CS6** on Windows 7 and still use it occasionally to make animations. I don't export FLAs to SWFs. I export them as MOVs, then convert the MOVs to MP4s. So, maybe CS6 won't be impacted by the Flash Player purge.

But..., when exporting MOVs, Flash Professional CS6 generates first an SWF file, which it converts to MOV, then deletes. In my Publish settings, I have "Target: Flash Player 11.2" (11.2 is the version that came with Flash Professional CS6) and SWF is the only output option. In my "Installed programs" panel I have the ActiveX and Firefox versions of the Flash Player (version 32.0.0, both recent). CS6's Player (version 11.2) does not appear on the list, but it is in the CS6 Program files folder.

I'm not sure what Adobe and Microsoft plan to do. But if it's to scrub every trace of the Flash Player (including 11.2?) will I still be able to export MOVs from Flash Professional CS6?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any problems with your routine. It's not like **MicroSoft** is going to suppress all **Flash**-related processes and software, they'll just stop shipping pre-installed **Flash** plugin for **IE** and **Edge**. Then, **CS6** was released in **2012**, long before the **Flash** shutdown sequence, it should be packed with its own standalone player that knows nothing of **2021**.

Comment: I reset my pc to February 2021 (past the Flash player death date) and everything still works. I've now read that Microsoft will kill Flash in supported versions of Windows (8 and 10) so hopefully I'm still OK with Win 7.